# How to create a shortcut to go at the end and sart of a line when I'm typing

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I'm coming from Mac OS. In this OS you can go at the end of line with de shortcut option + right and you can go at the start of a line when you're typing with the shortcut option + left. In ubuntu you can do this with the keys start and end. But I want to create a shortcut to do this without take away my hand from the letters. I was trying to create this shortcut like this. [this is in keyboard settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HU3fH.png)
I use vsCode prinarly and intellij and I need this for these editors.

My question is: It is possible to create this shortcut? And if possible how should I create it?

Comment: Do you primarily need it for a specific text editor?

Comment: I had edited the question and I explain that I use vs code and intellij